# How to import all imports automatically in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

- **In Android Studio**: I can have a settings set where, as I can set preferences so that when I am writing the code, The imports are
  automatically imported.
- **In Eclipse**: I can use `ctrl`+`shift`+`o` to perform similar operation.
- **In Xamarin Studio**: I am aware that I can put the cursor on the required word and press `Alt`+`Enter`

---

**What I am trying to do**:

- *Problem is that I have to import each imports individually. Is there a way to import all the imports automatically on a single click.*
- *Is it possible ?*

Answer (score 0):

It would be really useful but unfortunately, it isn't possible.

However, check this topic: [Getting the Most from Xamarin Studio](http://www.slideshare.net/Xamarin/getting-the-most-from-xamarin-studio-michael-hutchinson) you'll find there almost everything you may need in `Xamarin Studio`.

And this is a color scheme based on `dark visual studio` if you prefer dark screen for working.(I painted it myself):
[Xamarin Studio Dark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OSP9kby91mNWNBTTVFYjB6d1E/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Xamarin Studio Dark Preview]